# My application.js won't work and application.css won't update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I configured my application to work on Heroku, but I'm having a problem. In development mode, when I change a part of the CSS and refresh the browser, my CSS doesn't load.

I checked the logs, and the application.css doesn't load. I need it to load every time in development mode. Also, my application.js stopped working and I dont know why.

development.rb:

```
  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w( login.css )

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

enviroment.rb:

```
  config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

   # Enable the asset pipeline
   config.assets.enabled = true

   # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
   config.assets.version = '1.0'

   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

I compile the assets manually using `$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` and it works except for the application.js code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.reveal
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $( "#load_img" ).animate({
            height:"toggle",
      opacity:"toggle"
        });
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $( "#load_img" ).fadeOut('fast');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $("#flash_messages").fadeOut(3000)
    }, 
    2500);
});
```

Everything worked before deploying to Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't require the `application.js` file itself. Use [require_self](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-require_self-directive) like so:

```
//= require jquery
...
//= require_self

$(function() {});
```

Also pretty sure you're supposed to have a line break between the end of the includes and the start of the code in the `application.js` file itself.

Also this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( login.css )
```

should probably be in `application.rb` and not just `development.rb`, although if you are manually precompiling assets in development mode before deploying to Heroku it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks by the solution of .js this solve, very thanks, however in css i change the place how you say but this no solve my problem, i need compile the code to works the css, i want alter in .css and refresh browser working my change, im developing need this,well before I was in for heroku did not know what

Comment: As @Qumara pointed out you should run `$ rake assets:clean` to delete your compiled versions. Then you should be able to see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to see changes in development, you should not precompile your assets . To revert precompilation , try `rake assets:clean` . Also , it is not a good style to have js code in the manifest file `application.js`. Create a new file in `app/assets/javascripts/` and move the code there.

Comment: Well, it worked on localhost but on heroku as I had also run the precompile I did deploy but does not update heroku assets, which I need this solution?

Comment: I think in the deploy process there is a routine for precompile assets , so if you are precompiling them once again , it would be wrong.

Comment: Well but my modifications in my assets dont update in heroku, how i repair this if i run the compile manually, no works the rake assets:clean how in the localhost.

Comment: did you git commit after the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Precompiling your assets in development means that you're going to need to *keep* precompiling them to see any changes you make.

When you precompile assets, this will create a static css file in `public/assets`, and your web server will always serve static assets (eg. those in `public/assets`) before looking in the asset pipeline for new files.

Clean the precompiled files by either manually emptying `public/assets` or calling `rake assets:clean`.

When you deploy to Heroku, it will automatically compile the assets for you on deploy.

Comment: Well, it worked on localhost but on heroku as I had also run the precompile I did deploy but does not update heroku assets, which I need this solution?